# User friendly custom lists in Alfresco 4

Tags: list, sharepoint, alfresco

I'm trying to find a free replacement for Sharepoint 2010. Particularly I need custom lists creation functionality. I've read that Alfresco is a good replacement, but I can't seem to find any tutorial about custom data list creation. In Sharepoint you can create custom lists and fields out of the box, but it seems that with Alfresco you have to deal with XML code, which is not very user friendly, am I right?

If this is the case, is there any other kind of ECM with this functionality?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

With Alfresco, there are (3rd Party) tools providing functionality to model content with a gui at runtime, shielding users from ugly XML. Head over to http://addons.alfresco.com and search for "model". Alfresco Form-Model Management is one example.

That said, I can hardly imagine gui based content modeling qualifiying as a critical feature for the choice of an ECM as usually, developers do it infrequently (in one particular project).

Comment: Thanks Andreas, and you may not believe it but sometimes there are complex requirements like this. The user who I'm targeting will become the administrator and developer of the system, although he is not very technical.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that shows how to do custom data lists in Alfresco: http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2010/04/25/1156. I wrote it against Alfresco 3.3 and haven't tested it against the newest versions, but the content modeling stuff and most Share form config stuff haven't really changed that much since then so give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of what ECM is about is evolving rapidly. As someone who's built and managed SharePoint, Documentum, Wiki farms as well as ECM services, Web services, Data services and more in large environments, traditional Web ECM definitions are not what many companies are looking for now in solutions. The Web solution does more than "pure ECM". They are also not built and managed by developers and admins in many cases as well. "User admins" is becoming the norm. SharePoint's hierarchical delegation model and customization capabilities are not an end state but they are headed in the right direction. I'm guessing newer releases of Alfresco may move in this direction as well.